# a downloaded app gets automatically deleted from the folder upon double clicking

Tags: windows-10, drivers, security, windows-10-v1909

The downloaded app gets deleted and folder becomes locked.
I want to mirror my android phone screen on my Windows 10 laptop.I came across a blog here https://fossbytes.com/android-screen-mirroring-apps-pc/ ,
and I decided to give Vysor app a try.
I downloaded vysror for windows by link generated here https://vysor.io/ 
it redirects me to Vysor Downloads https://vysor.io/download/?return=https%3A%2F%2Fvysor.io%2F and then
I download the app in folder `C:\Users\downloaded software\vysor`.
I run the app for the first time then the app could open.
I saw in the bottom there was a line which said app needs Universal ADB drivers to run, so I downloaded
from here https://adb.clockworkmod.com/ universal adb drivers.
Now I installed them. In a location different than default installation folders for apps.
i.e.

```
 C:\Users\user data\installation\vysor\adb drivers\
```

Plug in my android phone via USB cable.I have had enabled developer options on my phone system settings before connecting phone to laptop via USB cable.

Now when I double click the app, to my surprise the app gets deleted by itself.
I did not do any thing and then now I again downloaded the app.
Now this time I get following error while trying to save the vysor app at the same location where it was downloaded previously.
The error is following
[download restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1qw9.jpg)
I then create a new sub folder name app inside this folder
`C:\Users\downloaded software\vysor`   inside this I create app so new download location becomes
`C:\Users\downloaded software\vysor\app`
here 
 I am able to download the app.
But again when I double click to run the app it gets deleted by itself ,(I have my phone connected via USB here)
and when I again download the app in folder
`C:\Users\downloaded software\vysor\app` , then I don't have permissions to download inside the folder, in which previously I downloaded.As in the screenshot.
So what could be possible problem I am not able to understand please suggest some thing what should I do?

The pop up from vysor page which generates the app version shows me it  downloaded Vysor-win32-ia32.exe which on double click on my windows 10 -1909 got automatically deleted. I am not clear what is happening.

The only program I could think of running is Malware bytes which starts with windows. But if it would have deleted then I should have got a notification that it deleted. Here after the app gets deleted the folder in which I downloaded the app that folder is locked for download.Even if I quit Malware bytes this problem is there.

Comment: I wonder if Windows Defender / Smart Screen is deleting the app. Look in Windows Defender Quarantine

Comment: Where is that location?

Comment: Click on Windows Defender in the System tray, Then Virus and Threat Protection under Current Threats.